# Communication link failure - MySQL+JDBC

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to connect to a MySQL docker container from a spring boot application. Every time I run my @SpringBootApplication class from eclipse, I am getting

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

I am running my docker container with below command line:

```
docker container run --name expenses-mysql-db --network expensetracker-net -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql
```

Below is my application.properties file content:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://expenses-mysql-db:3306/expensedb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

I expect the successful connection on running the spring api but its failing with above exception. Please help.

Comment: Please update this to include a [mcve]; in particular here that would include details of how you’re launching both the database container and the application.  (Are both in Docker, and are you `docker run --net` the same network for both of them?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expose mysql port outside of the docker container. Use -p to expose the ports.

```
docker container run -p 3306:3306 --name expenses-mysql-db --network expensetracker-net -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql
```

Comment: I tried the above command and it is still giving the same error. Is there any firewall/proxy settings I need to modify?

Comment: in your properties file, use the container's host machine ip (most probably localhost) instead of using expenses-mysql-db. Some thing similar to below:
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/expensedb

Comment: That worked on my local system. So when I create the production build and I move the mysql container to a different host, do I need to put the IP address of that host instead of container name?

Comment: Yes that would do it.